# What's wrong with my simple MSIL?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to generate the following class:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string MyMethod() { return "Hi"; }
}
```

My Emit code is as follows:

```
var assemblyBuilder = GetAssemblyBuilder("MyAssembly");
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Public);
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(string), new Type[] { });
var ilBuilder = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hi");
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

but when I invoke `MyMethod` on an instance of `MyType` I get an `InvalidProgramException`: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

I've tried changing the return type to `void` and using just `EmitWriteLine` and `Emit(OpCodes.Ret)`, which runs fine, so it must be the IL I've written here.

Am I missing something obvious here? A clear explanation would be helpful as I'm just getting started with Emit.

**Additional information from comments**:

The "original" IL is taken from the IL-generation in LINQ-pad.

Comment: @Selman22 I believe that is exactly what he has done, it looks like that when compiled to IL.

Comment: Some tips: 1) a tool like [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) will make it much harder to go wrong; 2) if unsure, compile what you **want** to do as regular C# code, then reverse-engineer the IL in ILDASM or reflector or similar

Comment: 3) "nop" in the IL is a sure sign that you've actually done #2, but looked at the output of a debug build. Don't do that; when doing #2, always use a release build.

Comment: @MarcGravell Comment a) That's actually what I did as per comments on Kendall's answer. Comment b) I see that now - release build produces Andrew's second half.

Comment: @MarcGravell Out of interest, what is the purpose of `Nop` in the debug code?

Comment: For those interested in where nop and branch comes from (debug build, they are optimized away in release): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667008/questions-about-hand-coded-il-based-on-disassembled-simple-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to removing the `OpCodes.Br_S` as pointed out by [@Kendall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551993/497356), you need to declare the local variable you're storing `"Hi"` to:

```
ilBuilder.DeclareLocal(typeof(string));
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hi");
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Additionally, I think the whole thing could be shortened to (this is what you get if you build your class with compiler optimizations *on*):

```
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hi");
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

(Just load the string, putting it on top of the evaluation stack, and then return the string).

If you wanted to replicate the version with compiler optimizations *off*, which I think is what you were originally trying to do:

```
Label returnLabel = ilBuilder.DefineLabel();

ilBuilder.DeclareLocal(typeof(string));
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
/* Load the string "HI" and put it on the evaluation stack. */
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hi");

/* Store "Hi" in the local variable we declared. */
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

/* Jump to the return label, which is, err the next line anyway: */
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, returnLabel);

/* Mark "returnLabel" here so we can jump to it: */
ilBuilder.MarkLabel(returnLabel);    

/* Load the contents of our local variable, put it on the evaluation stack: */
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

/* Return "Hi", which is now back on top of the evaluation stack: */
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

You need to define a label to branch to (using `ILGenerator.DefineLabel`, use `MarkLabel`, and then pass that label to `Emit` when you emit `OpCodes.Br_S`.

As you can see though, the branching is kind of pointless with a method this short.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the shortened version.

Comment: What is the equivalent in generated IL code of `DeclareLocal` as I can't see anything like it...

Comment: @dav_i: Are you using LINQPad? If so, the "IL" tab of that program won't show you declared locals

Comment: @dav_i: No problem. Only reason I know is because I ran into the same thing. Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

```
ilBuilder.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S);
```

Where were you intending to branch to? [`br.s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s.aspx) requires a signed byte argument that gives the offset to jump to.

Comment: Thanks Kendall, I was just copying the generated IL from an example class I made... and missed this obviously. How do you define where to `br.s` to as the generated code defines "line numbers".

Comment: You can pass it a Label using [`Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, theLabel)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahkzc1bh.aspx). See [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.label.aspx) for code samples on how to use them.

Comment: @dav_i you don't, usually; you use `DefineLabel`, and pass in the label - remembering also to use `MarkLabel` at the landing point.